# Why Are Ellipsis Appearing In My Textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

On a request form I have a textbox that the user is entering information into.  Once they enter the information, they save it, and then they can come back and edit the information. For some reason, the user can enter however many characters they want (which is fine) but after they save the form and reopen it, the textbox has cut off all the characters after 255 and added an ellipsis. The text is being stored in a database as a type "text" which allows up to 2000 characters.

Here is a picture of when a user inputs 2000 characters:

[image]

Here is a picture of after the user saves and edits the form:

[image]

This is the code I used to make the textbox:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Description, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" TextWrapping="Wrap" CharacterCasing="Normal"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" TextWrapping="Wrap" CharacterCasing="Normal"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Is this built in to the textbox? If not how can I get rid of this? I would like my user to be able to see everything that they have written.

Comment: Where is this data saved ??? To a database ? Check your datatype, if it is set to varchar(255), then you can only save up to 255 characters

Comment: The description is being stored as text which has a max length of 2000 characters so that should not be a problem.

Comment: Is the ellipsis an actual selectable character, or purely display?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Once the user goes back to edit the text, they can actually delete the individual periods as well as any other text.  So they are selectable characters.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Do the values saved in your database have the 3 periods, or are they stored with the full text?

Comment: I'm pretty sure something in your code is truncating the data and adding the ellipsis. TextBoxes do not do that by default, and even if you had a `TextBlock` with `TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"` it does not truncate and append to your string.

Comment: If the user can "delete the individual periods" then this is a string of three periods (`...`) rather than an ellipsis (`…`)

Comment: @BradleyUffner It is being saved with the three dots

Comment: It's gotta be something in your data layer.  You need to set a breakpoint and step in to every function that deals with that value. Either you will find the code that truncates the value, or will end up in a stored proc or trigger in your database as the culprit. As @Rachel said, this is NOT built in behavior of the `TextBox` control.

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody.  I am pretty sure the query is trying to convert the text into a varchar. Unfortunately, I do not have access to this at my job so I have to talk to my manager.  But once again thanks for your help!